# Query a colum to see if a value exists

Tags: powershell

I've tried searching for this online but haven't found anything which does what I need (I might be using the wrong keywords).

I've pulled some data from a MSSQL Database which returns the following:

```
Activity              Setting
--------              -------
All Operation         Enabled
Backup                Enabled
Restore               Enabled
Prune                 Enabled
Aux Copy              Enabled
Schedule              Enabled
Archive Check         Enabled
Tape Erase            Enabled
Offline content Index Enabled
Online Content Index  Enabled
```

How would I check to see if 'Backup' is enabled?

Edit:

I am pulling this information using the following:

```
$DB = "DB1"
$qcd = "SELECT JM.opName AS 'Activity',`
    CASE action` 
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Disabled'`
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Enabled'`
    END AS 'Setting'` 
    FROM JMJobAction AS J`
    LEFT JOIN JMJobOperationNames JM on JM.opType = J.opType`
WHERE clientId = 1` 
    AND appType = 0` 
    AND J.opType != 8` 
    AND appId = 1" 

$TestQuery = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $DB -Query $qcd -ServerInstance "RandomInstance\Instance1" -Verbose
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you currently pulling the data? Through powershell?

Comment: Yeah I am pulling the data through powershell using "Invoke-sqlcmd", and the above table is what is returned.

Comment: "How would I check to see if 'Backup' is enabled?" - for a specific record, or just _any_ record?

Comment: I just used "Backup" as an example but I will need to check if several of these activities are enabled/disabled.

Comment: "several of these" - specific ones, or a random selection/count?

Comment: You made me think about this differently and I can just check the "Setting" column for anything "Disabled" because nothing should be in this state anyway

I've already put this in my code, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest building a hashtable/dictionary from the resulting objects - this way you can quickly check an individual setting by name:

```
# Create hashtable
$settingsEnabled = @{}

# Populate with data from query
$TestQuery |ForEach-Object { $settingsTable[$_.Activity] = $_.Setting -eq 'Enabled' }
```

Now you can check a specific activity by name:

```
PS ~> $settingsEnabled['Backup']
True
```

To check whether *all* activities in a given list are enabled, flip the relationship around and check if any of them are NOT enabled:

```
$disabled = -split 'Backup Restore Prune Aux Copy Archive Check' |Where-Object { -not $settingsEnabled[$_] }

if($disabled){
  # At least 1 of the settings were not enabled
}
```